# Build with new class in referenced project failed without bin folder in source control, succeeded with it, why?

Tags: c#, tfs, build, reference, compilation

I have a solution in which Project2 references Project1. The reference points to the Project1.dll in Project1's bin folder.

I added a new class, Class1 to Project1 and used it in Class2 in Project2. When I checked in and built, I got an error resolving the namespace for Class1 from Class2 (the correct using statement was there). I added my local bin folder into source control, and the build succeeded.

This may be way off base, but my understanding of the bin folder is that it contains the output of a build after it has been compiled, so the dll for Project1 with the new class should be assembled before Project2, letting Class2 resolve Class1. Clearly, I'm at least a little wrong.

Can somebody explain why the build and reference behaved the way they did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely the reference from Project2->Project1 is a reference to the binary whereas it should be a reference to the project.

When you add the reference from Project2 to Project1, pick "Projects" in the "Reference Manager" rather than "Browse".  Then select the project you want to reference (Project1).

You can determine if it is a Project Reference or not by looking in the project file. If it is `Reference`, it is simply a Reference (which requires the existence of the DLL). If its `ProjectReference`, it is correctly setup as a Project Reference.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and removed bin from sc to test. I get the namespace error again. The path in the reference to P1 is now pointing to obj/debug/P1.dll, is that right?

Comment: yep, got <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj">..</ProjectReference>, still no dice. And Project1.csproj has <Compile Include="Class1.cs" /> in an <ItemGroup>

Comment: ah shoot, the csprpj in source control still has the bad reference. please hold.

Comment: okay im offically lost. When I hover over the reference in the solution explorer, it gives /bin/ as the path, but the csproj has it as a projectreference both in sc and locally, but I'm still hitting the error.

Comment: Build server, local builds A'OK

Comment: So I just spoke with a colleague on this. P1 gets pushed to a nuget server we have and gets referenced in other solutions outside of the Tfs project via nuget. We just moved one of these projects into the same Tfs project as P1, but its still pointing to the nuget version. When the project gets built on our server the nuget version that the new project's nuget reference overrides the current version, meaning no Class1. I'll check when I get back to the code. But I think switching that reference out will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Mattman's answer is correct, but there's more details that should be added. My references in Project2 were fine. There was another project, Project3, in the solution however, that was referencing a version of Project1 pulled from our private nuget server. When the solution builds, the DLL's all go to one place. The nuget version from Project3 was overwriting the project version of Project1, and since that version hadnt been updated to include Class1, I was getting the namespace error. I fixed the issue by removing the nuget reference from Project3 and pointing it directly to Project1 instead.